# Remove comma in radio selected numbers

Tags: column

My apologies if this has been asked already but I do not know what to reference.  When a column is created and the radio selection `Number (1, 1.0, 100)` is selected and a work order number, such as `123456` is entered, it will display as `123,456`.  How and where can I modify this?  Ive searched and my results are limited.

**EDIT:**
So far I have used `single line of text` but everything entered in this column would be numerical.  I would assume by limiting the column as numbers it would limit the chances of characters.  I have tried **Additional Column Settings** > **Number of decimal places:** **Dropdown set to zero** > **OK**, but I still get `123,456`

[image: Change Column]

[image: Column]

Answer (score 0):

When you create a Number field, under **Additional Column Settings** there is a setting called **Number of decimal places**. Select **0** in the dropdown and the decimal should not be set when the number entered is above thousand.

Comment: I tried that and it appears not to work.  Is there something that may over ride the selection?